# Garmin 510 lost data

Tags: garmin

I rode the Georgia 3 gap bike ride yesterday.  For me almost a lifetime accomplishment.  I used a Garmin 510 and when it reached 22% I plugged in an external charger.  The screen continued to indicate my ride.  However, when I finished and hit Save  there was no data preserved.  Is there any way to retrieve this data?

Thanks, Dave Holmes

Comment: Can you connect a 510 with a USB cable to your PC? I think your ride should be in the folder Garmin/Activities/ if it is there

Comment: There is a utility called the Fit File Repair Tool, which I think you can try for free. That sucks your data into an Access database so you can see exactly what data you captured. But if the device didn't capture it....it's gone

Comment: I've lost data a few times with my (first) E510 when I did 'strange' stuff. I would classify plugging in a charger during a ride as a 'strange' thing, i.e. the guys at Garmin push out products WAY too fast to account for such actions in their firmware....

Answer (score -1):

I have seen similar happen with my Garmin 500, regardless of duration/distance of the ride. For me, it occured when I had the Garmin plugged in to my Mac. I would delete activities from the Garmin and then safely remove (will also happen if you unsafely remove) the device. How to avoid this on Mac operating systems:

1. Delete your activities on Garmin
2. Empty trash via finder menu
3. Safely remove your Garmin device

I haven't tested if similar occurs on Windows or Linux.